# How do I use ffmpeg to convert a 30 fps video to 24 fps then to 25 fps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make a PAL DVD for my dad, of a movie shot in 24 fps which is stored in a 30 fps format. I tried directly converting it to 25 fps, but it is not a smooth result. A lot of duplicated frames - like 5 frames, then a dupe, then 3 frames, dupe, 8 frames, dupe, etc. However, when I convert it to 24 fps, it is smooth. Another video I have in 24 fps, and when I convert that to 25 fps, it is also pretty smooth (i.e., just one lost frame once a second, I suppose).

So I would like to have ffmpeg first convert the movie to 24 fps, and then convert this to 25 fps, to see if it will yield a smoother result than converting directly to 25 fps.

How do I do this?  I feel it is probably something to do with piping, but I don't know how to do this.

The input is 640 x 480 x 29.97 fps AVC1, and then I would like to losslessly convert to 24 fps, and pipe this into 720 x 576 x 25 fps MPEG2 video.  I have already found out how to do the scaling and padding filters, but I can't grasp the piping stuff. It's too complicated.

EDIT: I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Due to the temporal compression used in almost all modern video compressors converting framerates losslessly is an impossibility. You will always be losing quality.  For minimal generation loss you want to do the framerate conversion in one step.

Comment: Okay, but I don't think that's what I was aiming at.  The material consists of 30 fps video with 4 frames, then 1 duplicate frame, 4 new frames, 1 duplicate frame, etc., yielding 24 frames per second and 6 duplicate frames every second.  I wanted those duplicates to be discarded, and only keep the actual frames.

But when I tried it, it still didn't work. I have posted a new question describing the problem. https://superuser.com/questions/1220264/ffmpeg-how-to-pick-a-specific-pattern-of-frames-from-a-stream

Answer (score 1):

There is an unorthodox solution but apparently can give you the expected result. You will need to do two conversions, which I recommend to be done in two passes each one, in order to lose less quality possible though the whole process.

For the first step you need to convert your original video to a framerate that can be divisible by both of framerates (the original and the target). In this case, the lower number that is divisible by 30 and also 25 is 150. So, do a first conversion changing the <-r> parameter to 150. In order to keep the quality similar to the original video, you will need to multiply the original bitrate by 5. This is needed because the result video will have 5 times more frames per second than the original one. The audio tracks can be just copied.

The second step will be to take the result of the first conversion and convert to a video with the frame rate = 25. For this conversion you can use a bitrate 6 times smaller than the first step and the quality will be similar. The audio tracks can also be copied for this step.

The obtained video after this two conversions will not have the same quality of the original, but the result will be the best you can get using ffmpeg without doing any change on the original time of the movie and without distort the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following I tried based on examples I found on google, and it seemed to work. It didn't solve my problem, and yield smooth video, as I thought it would, but it did what my original question was aimed at.

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -r 24 -c:v rawvideo -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi pipe:1 | ffmpeg -i - -r 25 -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 4 -c:a mp2 -b:a 192k "%~nx1.vob"
```

This command took the input file %1 which was 30 fps and converted it to 24 fps, and then piped the decompressed frames and decompressed audio to another instance of ffmpeg which converted them to 25 fps in mpeg2video and mp2 audio.