# ffmpeg: How to pick a specific pattern of frames from a stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

Can anyone help me convert a 30 fps stream of video to 24 fps?

The original material is a film. It seems to be shot in 24 fps, because the stream seems to consist of a series of 4 frames followed by one duplicate, and then over again. 4 frames, 1 dupe, 4 frames, 1 dupe, 4 frames, 1 dupe, etc.,
making 24 frames per second and 6 duplicates per second.

When I ask ffmpeg to convert this material to 24 fps, strange things happen.

When I convert a 20 second clip 3 minutes into the movie, to mpeg2video at 24 fps (using the flag -r 24), I get a smooth movie, except for one of the first frames which is a duplicate.  However, when I first try to copy the same clip into a separate file, and then try to convert this to mpeg2video, I get a staccato movement of a few frames, then a dupe, then some more frames, a dupe, etc. etc., with seemingly random numgers of frames between the dupes.  So - the same clip, but smooth in the first case, and staccato in the second!

However, when I use ffmpeg to convert the exact same file to x264, I get the same staccato movement for about 30 frames, and then the movement becomes totally smooth!

What could be going on here?

Is there some way of specifically telling ffmpeg to only use 4 frames, then to skip one, and looping this all through the movie?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's the specific issue at hand, for which you can use the select filter, or the general problem, of removing duplicate frames present in an unknown pattern introduced during the telecine process.

For the former,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='mod(n+1,5)',setpts=N/24/TB out.mp4
```

For the latter, the [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) filter may be useful

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/24/TB out.mp4
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you.  I will go right to work experimenting with it, and report on it.     I was going to ask if there was a way of dropping every 5th frame, or, alternatively, asking ffmpeg to pick the frames based on numbers in a text-file, but this mpdecimate sounds great - if I can get it to work.  I'll try your suggested parameters first...   Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks Mulvya!  I tried both the suggested commands, and both seem to work flawlessly!  They workj when I convert the file from the beginning, but when I try to convert from a specific timepoint ahead in the movie, the select= command still has dupes, which must be because the framepoint I specified wasn't exactly divisible by 5. So for this to work, I guess I would have to tell ffmpeg to skip 1-4 frames before using the select='mod(n+1,5)' method.     But no matter, what I wanted to do in the first place now works! And the mpdecimate-method works in both cases.   So thanks! Very much.

Comment: Ehm, I have been trying to do what you suggested, and it seemed to work, and the video is perfectly smooth with no duplicate frames, it looks like, but now when I watch the whole movie, the video goes out of sync with the audio after some minutes.  I don't get it.

Comment: When I use the select= filter, whether I use -r 24 or -r 25 (which is my final target fps) it goes out of sync, but also when I don't use the -r flag, and just let it stay at 30 fps, it ALSO goes out of sync, even though the output looks identical to the input, with 4 frames, 1 duplicate, etc. etc.!  However, when I don't use the select= filter, and just use the -r 24 flag, the synchronization is maintained.     Do you have an idea of what might be the problem?

Comment: For 25 fps output, go with `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -r 25 out.mp4`. One frame should be duplicated for each second - that can't be helped.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I don't care about one frame being duplicated every second - I think that won't look so bad.       But I can see that the AV goes out of sync. After 1h47m10 seconds of the original movie, when I try dropping every 5th frame, the product video is 3 seconds shorter.    I wonder, is it because the original is 29,97 fps, and not exactlt 30 fps, so that when I am dropping every 5th frame, in the end it goes out of sync by those 3 seconds?  I don't really understand what's happening...

Comment: When trying to convert this movie, I also sometimes get error messages from ffmpeg like "Past duration 0.717705 too large", and many of them, including different numbers.   I haven't seen it today, but suddenly I got it again, when trying out your suggestion above.   But I didn't get it earlier, but still got the sync problem, so I don't think this is the cause, but what do I know?

Comment: It seems to have worked! The audio and video are in alignment. I don't understand it! Why did it work? I tried your suggestion of "-r 25 -vf mpdecimate" without "setpts=N/24/TB." The new file is still not as long as the original - it is 2 seconds shorter, and all through the process, I got thousands of error messages of the "Past duration 0.750069 too large"-kind, but otherwise it seems to be fine.  Do you have any clue why the decimate filter didn't work when the "setpts" filter was included, and why the "select=" filter didn't work either?  Well, again, thank you so much.